# Mahout 0.11.1 Spark-Shell NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-spark, jersey, mahout

I am trying to get the Mahout Spark-Shell to run on the Cloudera QuickStart VM

```
Mahout: Version 0.11.1

Spark: Version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.1

Java: 1.7.0_67
```

.bashrc is set as

```
export MAHOUT_HOME=/home/cloudera/Desktop/Mahout_0_11_1
export MAHOUT_LOCAL=true
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
```

When I run the Mahout Spark-Shell I get the following error message.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.ApiRootResource$.getServletHandler(ApiRootResource.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:466)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.package$.mahoutSparkContext(package.scala:91)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.shell.MahoutSparkILoop.createSparkContext(MahoutSparkILoop.scala:89)
...
```

This is then followed by:

```
Mahout distributed context is available as "implicit val sdc".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLListener.<init>(SQLListener.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1033)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:11)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in spark-env.sh,

add

export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/path/to/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)

and make sure that jersey-servlet-1.9.jar is on the classpath.

go through all of your *-env.sh scripts and be as explicit as possible about setting the environment variables, checking each, and then checking the logs for errors.

cd /
find . -name jersey-servlet-1.9.jar
and make sure the path where this file is found is on your classpath

Edit:
Add jersey-server-1.9.jar to $MAHOUT_HOME/lib/ directory.

Comment: According to the spark branch 1.5 pom.xml at this link https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml, there should be three jersey jars.  jersey-server-1.9.jar, jersey-core-1.9.jar and jersey-json-1.9.jar.  The class that is not being found is in the jersey-server jar.  You could download the jars from maven central.  Or, they may have been copied to another directory on your server.  cd /      then    find . -name jersey-server*.jar and see if you can find it.  if you do, copy it into that hadoop lib.

Comment: I have added that file and it still seems to not be working. Mahout says when I start the shell "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable" if this is relevant.

spark-env.sh (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/442a91fd1c808b1f9224) and I have the files in the /usr/lib/hadoop/lib directory (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/817f4859958a833e053a)

Comment: [`jersey-sevlet`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet) is not introduced until 1.10. Spark uses 1.9. In the 1.9 version the `ServletContainer` is included, but in 1.10, it is put into the `jersey-servlet` artifact with different packaging. So to make it compatible, I would use the 1.9 version, if that's what Spark uses.

Comment: For the "Unable to load native hadoop library for your platform" error.  go to HADOOP_HOME/bin/native/Linux...    In there, you will see a task-controller executable.  You need to make sure this file is owned by root.  chown root task-controller.  Even more weird, you need to chmod 4750 task-controller.  Yes, that's right, 4750.  Also, if you change the debug level of your root logger to DEBUG, you will get more detailed error messages to this effect.

Comment: I ended up placing the jersey-server-1.9.jar file in the $MAHOUT_HOME/lib directory and the error was fixed. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Cool.  Glad to hear it.